# Python: ImportError: No module named Selenium Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using python 3.6 on windows10. I created a virtual environment with:

```
python -m venv venv
```

Then I installed a few packages and also installed selenium with the command:

```
pip install selenium
```

However when I import selenium, I get an error saying:

```
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

when I run the script in cmd. But when I run the same code in VSCode, it gives no errors.
I am unable to understand the reason behind this. Also, I tried uninstalling and installing the whole environment again. No changes observed.

Note: I am planning to deploy this project to Heroku. So please give any suggestions you think would be necessary to do when deploying to Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am very sorry for this... but it just worked by running it with:

```
python main.py
```

Answer (score 1):

To install selenium

```
C:\Automation\DevelopBranch> pip install selenium
```

Can you please check `Selenium` is installed.

```
C:\Automation\DevelopBranch>pip freeze
selenium==3.141.0
urllib3==1.25.6
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' comm
and.
```

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver:
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"path of chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Yes, I checked with pip freeze, selenium is installed.